# users online status issue

Tags: views, users

it is a Author Status Issue: let's to show either a user is online or offline. If a user is online then it will show `>Online` if offline then like this `>Offline`
So how to show it?

Answer (score 1):

[User Stats](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) is a good basic plugin that provides this functionality within Views and Rules. Install the plugin, then add a field or filter to your views results.

Answer (score 1):

[Author Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/author_pane) is a block of information about a given user, like those typically found on a forum post, but can be used in other places as well. From core, it collects the user picture, name, join date, online status, contact link, and profile information. In addition, any module or theme can feed it more information via the preprocess system. All of this information is then gathered and displayed using a template file.